# Writing log to a "lock for edit" file, which throws exception. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, logging

I have multithreaded operation running, each one append some info to my log file. The problem is, sometimes log file is locked for editing and at the same time is accessed by other thread, which throws an exception. How can i make sure the log is properly written?

here are the snippet

```
 try
 {
  File.AppendAllText(fileName, appendString);
 }
 catch (System.Exception )
 {
 }
```

for now, i just ignore the exception. this cause some of the logs are not written.

Comment: Using File.AppendAllText() is a miserly expensive way to log.  Look at log4net for a much improved way of logging.  No problem with locks of course.

Comment: You might consider looking at a free logging framework, like NLog.  The challenges associated with logging are well understood at this point and using an existing logging framework will save you the trouble of having to rediscover and implement the solution yourself.

Comment: Actually, i did look for log library after frustratingly cannot solve this problem. Did try log4net and was not successfull. Apparently, log4net was last updated on 2006 and does not properly support visual studio 2010. plus editing the configuration was very confusing and tedios. Wasted hours on log4net and in the end was unsuccessfull. Switch to nlog and within minutes got it up and running. problem with nlog is that is doesnt support wpf element(richtextbox support is for windows forms only). Right now trying to use memory target to write to richtextbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to synchronize your log writes.**

What happens is that two threads are appending to the log file at the same time.

Try the following:

```
class Program
{
    public static readonly object LogWriteLock = new object();

    // The rest of your Program class.
}
```

Then, when writing the log:

```
lock (Program.LogWriteLock)
{
    File.AppendAllText(fileName, appendString);
}
```

What this does is the following. You create an object (`Program.LogWriteLock`) which you use to "synchronize" your log operations on. Then, when one thread is writing to the log file, the next thread will simply wait on the first thread to complete, and write after that.

You can even wrap this into a nice little helper class and you get something like this:

```
public static class LogHelper
{
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    public static void AppendToLog(string appendString)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("log.txt", appendString);
        }
    }
}
```

*Replace `"log.txt"` with your actual log file location.*

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I wonder why google hasnt led me to this kind of solution. Gonna try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a thread thats sole purpose is to update the log, then having your other threads just add to a thread safe queue that the log updater thread will process?

This seems like a better idea than writing to the file from all of the other threads.

Comment: Actually, i did thought of that. Problem is, Im not quite familiar with multithread and I dont know where to start. I dont even know the keyword to search.